# How to propagate the ajax.abort() to the controller

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a problem with propagating the aborting of my ajax call to the controller.

I have a JavaScript function in View code that may be called by a user at any point. This then transmits a value to the controller using ajax. The controller then does a time consuming opertion on the Input and returns a result.

What I want is that when user calls the function if it is already doing the time consuming opertation to either:

Stop and to start again with the new Input. In essence I need to propagate the abort call up to my controller code and deal with it accordingly

OR

I need to be able to run multiple simultaneous instances of the controller function.

Is this possible? and what is the best way to do it.

View Code

```
var AJAXSetPalette = null;    

function DoSometing(Input) {

    if (AJAXSetPalette)
        AJAXSetPalette.abort();

    AJAXSetPalette = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ImagesAnalysis/DoSomething",
        datatype: "json",
        traditional: true,
        data: Input,
        success: function (Data) {
            DoJSFunction(Data);
        }
     return;
 }
```

Controller

```
 public int DoSomething(int Input)
 {
    int RetVal
    //Calculate RetVal from Input, very Time Consuming
    Return RetVal
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried doing the ajax call multiple times?  I don't think there is a reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: The calls to the controller function seemed to be queued somewhere. the 2nd call DoSomething only runs when the first has finished

Comment: Perhaps you need to read this: [Using an Asynchronous Controller in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Looks promising, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a client-server issue. Connections between a client and a server in HTTP are not persistent. The client opens a connection to the server and makes a request. The connection is then closed. The server processes the request, opens a connection back to the client, and sends the response.

*Note: As of HTTP 1.1, this is not technically true any more. Connections are actually persisted in many cases over HTTP 1.1, but merely to reduce the delay from having to re-establish the connection. In principle, both the client and server still behave as if the connection has been closed.*

The point is that once your AJAX request is sent, the server is merrily on its way processing the request. If the client should abort the request, there's no notification given to the server. When the server attempts to send the response, it will simply be refused, and the server will disregard it and move on to the next request.

That's how the TCP/IP and HTTP protocols were designed to behave, and it's what makes the Internet possible as a loosely connected network of nodes that can drop off or come online at will.

Long and short, there's no way to cancel the request on the server-side from the client once it's been sent.

For your scenario, the best thing would be to simply disable the user's ability to issue another request until the server has responded or some timeout period has elapsed. If the request is so resource intensive and you can call it as many times as you want as fast as you want, that's a huge opportunity for a DoS attack